# Whats the relation between First Responder and hitTest methods?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, first-responder

I understand how the system find the view handles touch events by calling the following methods on a view and its subviews

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

But I don't understand the role of first responder in this mechanism.

Does firstResponder represents the start point of the hitTest traverse?

Comment: My knowledge is if the UIView control is hit it becomes the first responder. Thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a complete reading of the first article

[Using Responders and the Responder Chain to Handle Events](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/using_responders_and_the_responder_chain_to_handle_events)

in Apple documentation

[Touches, Presses, and Gestures](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures)

Short answer:

1. Touch events are delivered directly to the first responder.

> When your app receives an event, UIKit automatically directs that event to the most appropriate responder object, known as the first responder.

2. First responder is determined by hit-testing.

> UIKit uses view-based hit-testing to determine where touch events occur. Specifically, UIKit compares the touch location to the bounds of view objects in the view hierarchy. The hitTest(_:with:) method of UIView traverses the view hierarchy, looking for the deepest subview that contains the specified touch, **which becomes the first responder for the touch event**.

3. If the first responder does not handle the event, the event is then passed from responder to responder in the active responder chain.

Comment: Thanks man, I've read the document, But what still confuses me is
1. The touch event is first delivered to the AppDelegate, then all the way down to the topmost view on the screen by recursively using HitTest and PointInside, right? After that, the topmost view will be the first responder. But the diagram in the first linked document show the process starts from the views. How does the system find those views?

Comment: 2. When would the `next` (next responder) property be used in the chain? I checked it in a demo project that setting root view controller's `next ` to nil doesn't affect the UIKit to find the view I touched.

Comment: from the first linked document "You can alter the responder chain by overriding the next property of your responder objects. When you do this, the next responder is the object that you return."

Comment: The touch event is first delivered to the first responder, not App Delegate. Generally, the first responder is the deepest(foremost) subview on screen.

Comment: 1. touch event occurred. 2. hit test from bottom to up 3. first responder determined. 4.  if it does not handle the touch, the event is passed to the next responder 5. the next responder, by default, is its super view, or associated view controller, or window, or application, from up to bottom.

Comment: If you follow this sequence, changing the `next` of the root view controller has no effect in most cases, because it never got the chance to be the first responder, some subview might already handled the event. If it is not the first responder, it has no chance to send event to its next responder!

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of relationship between them, except that the result of hit test *might* cause the window to make the hit view become `firstResponder`.

`firstResponder` is all about keyboard events and, at least on macOS, menu item actions and commands like `cut`, `copy`, `paste`, `undo` etc...

When a keyboard event is received by the app from the Window Server, it goes to the `firstResponder`.  If it's not interested in it, then it goes up the chain to `nextResponder` until it exhausts the responder chain.  On macOS there are related but separate concepts of the `mainWindow` and `keyWindow`.  They are usually the same, but can be different.  If they are different the responder chain first starts with the `keyWindow`, and when that chain is exhausted, it then goes to the `mainWindow`.  Then the application gets a crack at it.  Then the application's delegate.  Then if it's a document based app, the document and then the document's delegate.

On iOS, I'm a little fuzzy on the exact details, but it's similar. Actually I think it's simpler, because you don't have multiple windows.

Hit testing on the other hand is all about the view heirarchy.  So the app finds which window (on macOS) the hit occurs in, then from there it proceeds down to it's immediate subviews, and then down its subviews, etc... until it finds a leaf view that is hit.